# I don't Understand why I'm using the letter i in this situation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm just starting in c++ and working on a simple console app, and the instructor didn't explain some things. In this one part he said to code this in,

```
//increment the turn number
MyCurrentTry++;

//setup a return variable
FBullCowCount BullCowCount;

//loop through all letters in the guess
int32 HiddenWordLenth = MyHiddenWord.length();
for (int32 i = 0; i < HiddenWordLenth; i++) {
    // compare letters against the hidden word
    for (int32 j = 0; j < HiddenWordLenth; j++) {
        // if they match then       
        if (Guess[i] == MyHiddenWord[i]) { //if they're in the same place

            if (i == j) { // increment bulls 
                BullCowCount.Bulls++; // Incriment Bulls

            }
            else
            {
                BullCowCount.Cows++; //must be a cow
            }
```

Now I understand this is a bit messy (sorry) but if someone could explain possibly why I'm using `i` and what `i` does (is it some sort of variable, or what?), I would greatly appreciate it. If my question isn't clear or I'm doing something wrong let me know (The instructor said this "i" is going to end up creating a bug but I would like to know the purpose of it anyways)

Comment: `i` is just the commonly used name for the variable that is the subject of a `for` loop.  It comes from the words *iterative* and *increment*.

Comment: i,j,k are used as index variables in general, even from outside computer science, like in mathematics.

Comment: It's not clear if you are asking why you use `i` instead of some other name or letter, or why the use of `i` in `Guess[i]` and `MyHiddenWord[i]`

Comment: I didn't understand what the purpose of `i`. Like if it was a variable, or some other thing i didn't know. Thanks for pointing this out as I see how this could be confusing ;D I tried to revise my post but as I'm a noob in programming I don't know what to make it say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` and `j` are simply counter variables in your `for` loops. They could just as well be named *ingrid* and *john*. Their only purpose is to act as counters as your loop iterates through.

Comment: s/they're/their/g

Comment: So they're like variables to hold info, (like setting them to 0)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this till just now. Correct, they're variables that hold information about your loop.